# The flow of a Killing vector field preserves submanifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, isometry

I am wondering if the flow of a [Killing vector field](http://%3Chttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field%3E) preserves the submanifolds?

In fact, on a Riemannian manifold $(M,h)$ I have a Killing vector field $W$. Let $\varphi:I\times M\to M$ be its flow. We know that $\varphi_t:=\varphi(t,.):M\to M$ is an isometry.

> I can say that given a submanifold $A\subset M$, $\varphi_t(A)\subset A$ and therefore, $d\varphi_t:T_pA\to T_pA$?

> Or, in othe wrods, $\forall u\in T_pA$, $d\varphi_t(u)\in T_pA$?

I will appreciate any comments or answers in advance!

Comment: No. Consider a path.

Comment: Certainly not in general. Consider what happens to a point (a $0$-manifold) under the flow of a Killing field that does not vanish at that point.

Comment: there are some conditions that guarantee it?

Comment: If the field $X$ is tangent to the submanifold, i.e., $X_a \in T_a A$ for all $a \in A$, then the flow of $X$ preserves $A$ locally around any point (but, without other conditions, may not globally). But that's true for all vector fields on a smooth manifold, not just Killing fields on a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: N.B. for any submanifold $A$ of a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ the vector fields tangent to the submanifold comprise a Lie subalgebra of the Lie algebra of Killing fields of $g$.

Comment: Thanks, guys for the useful comments!

Comment: What you can say is that the zero set of a Killing field is the disjoint union of connected totally geodesic submanifolds (possibly with different dimensions).

Comment: Thanks for all comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Eucledean metrix $\phi_t(x)=x+tu$ is the flow of the vector field $X(x)=u$ where $u\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is not zero. Take the circle of radius $1$ center at $0$, it is not preserved by $\phi_t$ and $X$ is tangent to $C$ at $(0,1)$ if $u=(1,0)$.